# VB.NET IIF Statement

Tags: vb.net

In VB.NET I am trying to use SQL Parameter to send data to SQL Server Database, I am trying to convert string to decimal with following code if the value of the datagridrow is nothing then send 0 or use conversion to decimal argument.

```
SQL.Addparam("@amt", IIf(IsNothing(DataGridView2.Rows(index).Cells(7).Value), 0, CDec(DataGridView2.Rows(index).Cells(7).Value)))
```

(SQL and Addparam is called from class I created)

But with this code I get error "System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Decimal' is not valid.'"

I need help on this please.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific issue is clearly that your "empty" cell does not actually contain a null reference, i.e. `Nothing`, but rather an empty `String`. You would need to test for an empty `String` as well as or instead of `Nothing`. If your cell might contain either `Nothing`, an empty `String` or a `Decimal` value, this should work:

```vb
Dim cellValue = DataGridView2.Rows(index).Cells(7).Value

SQL.Addparam("@amt",
             If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(CStr(cellValue)),
                Decimnal.Zero,
                CDec(cellValue)))
```

Note the use of `If` rather than `IIf` and an actual `Decimal` value for the zero. `String.IsNullOrEmpty` will detect `Nothing` or an empty `String` in a single call.

That's really not the best solution though.

It appears that you are using an unbound grid and then looping through the rows and saving each row individually. That is really the wrong way to go. What you should be doing is creating a `DataTable` with the appropriate schema, populating it from the database if required, binding it to the grid, performing the required edits and then just saving the whole `DataTable` in one go with a single call to `Update` on a data adapter.

If you do that then an "empty" cell will contain `DBNull.Value` and ADO.NET will automatically save *NULL* to your database. If you don't want *NULL* values in a column then just set the `AllowDBNull` property to `False` and the `DefaultValue` property to whatever you want instead.

To create the `DataTable` schema, you can call `Fill` on a data adapter to do that and populate with data, or you can call `FillSchema` to not retrieve any data. Alternatively, you can just build the schema yourself.

Comment: You got me right, I am trying to save values from datagridview row by row and adding more values which are not part of datagridview but need to be added to database. I am sure what you are suggesting is the way to go, will work on it.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a solution to your immediate problem but I would definitely suggest approaching the whole thing differently. Check out my ADO.NET examples [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872).

Comment: Awsome, Thanks a lot for your help. I am working on datatable and this will still be usefull for sending data from datagridview to datatable. I am trying to not touch database as the old program needs to be working and I dont know how that reacts to my change of database.